# Qlikview Automate past 12 months selection

Tags: date, business-intelligence, qlikview, qliksense

I have a combo chart which shows the average days it took for a person to pay their bill.

The Dimension of the Chart is `= [Pay Month Year last 12 months]`

There are no Dimension limits

There is 1 expression which is called `Average` and its definition is:

```
avg({< InvoicefromSqlType = {'Invoices'},[Is Invoice Paid] = {'Y'},[Is Positive Amount] = {'Y'},[Is Paid last 12 months] = {'Y'},DueGroups=,[Pay Month Year last 12 months]=>}[Days to Pay])`
```

Its is sorted by expression, which is `[Pay Month Year last 12 months]`

Now the above fields are built up like this:

**[Pay Month Year last 12 months]**

```
If([Pay Date] >= '$(vPeriodS12)',[Pay Month year]) as [Pay Month Year last 12 months],
```

> PayLoadOrder:

```
Load * Inline [Pay Month Year last 12 months
May-2014
Jun-2014
Jul-2014
Aug-2014
Sep-2014
Oct-2014
Nov-2014
Dec-2014
Jan-2015
Feb-2015
Mar-2015
Apr-2015
May-2015
];
```

Now what is happening is every month when it reaches the end, the next month is needing to be manually added and the first month removed (e.g. in the above I would delete the line May-2014 and at the end add the line Jun-2015)

Also if there are months defined which there is no data for yet i.e. you have Jun-2015 hard coded and the current month this May-2015 then Jun-2015 will show data from 2014 and the order of the months will get mixed up.

What I want to do is completely remove the need to hard code the months above and have this done its self.

If there are any more information you need let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a "sort order" table that you may have to manually update, it may be worth doing the following:

- Create a new field derived from `[Pay Date]` that returns a month and year that you can sort. For example:

  ```
  dual(date(makedate(year([Pay Date]),num(month([Pay Date]))),'MMM-yyyy'),
  year([Pay Date]) * 100 + num(month([Pay Date]))) as PayMonthYear
  ```

  Here, the `dual` function allows you to associate a different representation of a field value to its underlying value. For example, here we set the underlying data to be the year of `[Pay Date]` added to the month, but state that it should be displayed as `MMM-yyyy`. For example, internally, QV still sees the value 201502, but displays it as Feb-2015. This means you can sort it correctly based on its underlying value.

  Using `dual` is a big topic, please consult the built-in help for QV for more information.
- Change your chart dimension from `[Pay Month Year last 12 months]` to use `PayMonthYear` and set the sort to ascending. This would then mean that your months would be sorted correctly, even if a new month was added.
- Remove table `PayLoadOrder` from your script.

**Alternative Method**

An alternative would be to use a calendar table which joins on your `Pay Date` field. This would achieve the same thing, however, you could also integrate your "year to date" indicator into the calendar as well and remove it from your main table. An example I quickly threw together is shown below:

```
MinMax:
LOAD 
   Max([Pay Date]) AS MaxDate,
   Min([Pay Date]) AS MinDate
RESIDENT MyData;

LET varMinDate = Num(Peek('MinDate',0,'MinMax'));      // 0 is first record
LET varMaxDate = Num(Peek('MaxDate',-1,'MinMax'));      // -1 is last record
LET varToday = Num(Today());

MasterCalendar:
LOAD
    monthstart([Pay Date]) >= monthstart(AddMonths(Today(),-12)) as PaidInLast12MonthsFlag,
    dual(date(makedate(year([Pay Date]),num(month([Pay Date]))),'MMM-yyyy'),year([Pay Date]) * 100 + num(month([Pay Date]))) as PayMonthYear
    [Pay Date];
LOAD
   date($(varMinDate) + RecNo() - 1,'DD/MM/YYYY') as [Pay Date]
AUTOGENERATE num($(varMaxDate)) - num($(varMinDate)) + 1;

DROP TABLE MinMax;
```

So, in the above, the field `PaidInLast12MonthsFlag` is equal to `-1` if the value of the `[Pay Date]` field occurs in the last 12 months, `0` otherwise. You could use this in your set analysis expression as a filter. Furthermore, you can use `PayMonthYear` as your chart dimension.